# PHP/OS X: permissions on new file created with move_uploaded_file()

Tags: php, macos, apache

My environment is Apache on OS X with PHP.

My script creates file with `move_uploaded_file()` in the folder /www/mysite/uploads/ but the permissions are set as such:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 _www  wheel   857K 23 Jul 23:10 temp.png
```

What I want is for the permissions to be set to:

```
-rw-rw----  1 _www  admin   857K 23 Jul 23:10 temp.png
```

How do I do that?

Comment: CHMOD? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chmod.1.html or http://www.macinstruct.com/node/415

Comment: Check the receiving directories permissions ... should be set to something like 0755 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

You can use chmod() after moving the file.

```
move_uploaded_file($filename , $destination);
chmod($destination, 0644);
```

http://php.net/chmod